# Compact set and continuous function

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(E,d), (E',d')$ be two metric space, and $f:E\rightarrow E'$ an injective function such that the image of any compact set from $E$ is compact in $E'$.

How can I prove that $f$ is continuous?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be easy if $E$ is compact: then $f(E)$ is compact and $f^{-1}: f(E)\to E$ is continuous between compact spaces and hence a homeomorphism. But I'm not sure what might happen if $E$ is noncompact..

Comment: Note that it cease to be true as soon as $E$ is not a metric space.

Comment: please i found an other proof: let $(x_n)$ a convergent sequence (to $x$) in $E,$ and let $K=\{x_n, n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x\}$ be compact, $f: K\rightarrow f(K)$ is bijective, and they proved that $f^{-1}$ is continuous...
after they proved that $f^{-1}$ is continuous they says"
as $f$ is bijective on the compact $K$ then $f$ is homeomorphisem so $f$ is continuous on $K$ in particular we have: $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n)=f(x_0)$
i do not understand the use of the continuity of  $f^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \to x$. Let $y_n = f(x_n), y=f(x)$. We want to show that $y_n \to y$.

Let $D_n = \{x_n,x_{n+1},...\} \cup \{x\}$ and 
$R_n = \{y_n,y_{n+1},...\} \cup \{y\}$. We see that both sets are compact. Let
$D = \cap_n D_n$,$ R = \cap_n R_n$. We see that $D = \{x\}$.

Note that since $R_n$ is compact, it contains all accumulation points of the sequence $y_n$. Hence $R$ contains all accumulation points of the sequence $y_n$. Also note that any subsequence of $y_n$ must have an accumulation point.

Hence, to show that $y_n \to y$, it is sufficient to show that $R = \{y\}$.

Suppose $z \in R$, but $z \neq y$. Then $f^{-1}(\{z\}) \cap D_n \neq \emptyset$ for all $n$. However, since $f$ is injective, we see that $f^{-1}(\{z\})$ is a 
single point, hence, in fact, we have $f^{-1}(\{z\}) \subset D_n $ for all $n$.

This implies $\{x\}=f^{-1}(\{z\})$, a contradiction. Hence $R = \{y\}$.

**Note**: To see the necessity of injectivity in this proof, take $f=1_\mathbb{Q}$, then any set is mapped into a compact set, but $f$ is
clearly not continuous.

Comment: where is used the fact that $f$ is injective ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for asking.

Comment: please i found an other proof: let $(x_n)$ a convergent sequence (to $x$) in $E,$ and let $K=\{x_n, n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x\}$ be compact, $f: K\rightarrow f(K)$ is bijective, and they proved that $f^{-1}$ is continuous...
after they proved that $f^{-1}$ is continuous they says"
as $f$ is bijective on the compact $K$ then $f$ is homeomorphisem so $f$ is continuous on $K$ in particular we have: $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n)=f(x_0)$
i do not understand the use of the continuity of  $f^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the image of a sequence $x_n \to x$ together with $x$...

Comment: I have this idea take a convergent sequence and prove that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ but how how to use the fact that f is injective and how we use the compact set ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou If $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $x$, then the set $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x\}$ is compact.

Comment: why ? please it is closes ok but why compact ?

Comment: @egreg So it follows that $(f(x_n))_n$ has a convergent subsequence. But why is $f(x_n)$ itself convergent?

Comment: $(f(x_n))_n$ is a sequence with a cluster point within $\{f(x_n)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{f(x)\}$. But how do we know it converges to $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou The set is compact because, if $U$ is an open set containing $x$, then $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n\notin U\}$ is finite. So from an open cover we can extract a finite subcover.